# Excel SUM values of a mixed Column with line-broken cells AND single-line cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, multiline

It'd be pretty obvious but I'm wondering for days: How can I SUM a column of a mix of single-line values and multi-line (Alt+Enter) values in Excel?

[image]

In this example, I'd like to display the Sum on the second column (7.5+12+11+1.2+2.5+3) which is 37.2. Should be easy but how can I get this in Excel?

I've tried several ways but no success so far. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would work with your version of Excel, using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd> & <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUM(
    FILTERXML(
        "<m><b>" &
            SUBSTITUTE(
                TEXTJOIN(
                    CHAR(10),
                    ,
                    A1:A4
                ),
                CHAR(10),
                "</b><b>"
            ) & "</b></m>",
        "//b"
    )
)
```

---

Also one needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Alternative approach using **`MS365`** functions, without any <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper functions.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A1:A4,
     b,CHAR(10),
     SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(b&a,b,SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,b,))+1)),,,0),b))))
```

---

If the number of line feeds is always 2 then.

```
=SUM(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(CHAR(10)&A1:A4,CHAR(10),{1,2},,,0),CHAR(10)))
```

---

Another alternative approach for Excel 2019 users.

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(TRIM(
  MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,CHAR(10),REPT(" ",100)),COLUMN($A$1:$Z$1)*100-99,100))+0,0))
```

---

the above formula needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

Comment: While the first 2 didn't work, the last one did the trick in Office 2019. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

"Alt + Enter" is `CHAR(10)` so `TEXTSPLIT` with it and then sum:

```
=SUM(MAP(A1:A4,LAMBDA(z,SUM(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(z,CHAR(10),,1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: This gives an error for me:
![IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya39A.png).
What could be the problem? I'm using Excel 2019.

Comment: You're problem is that you're using excel 2019.  Use the free web version of excel to get the function to work.

Comment: You didn't mention you version of Excel in a post so assumption was made that you are using newest version. My solution won't work in Excel 2019, use @Mayukh Bhattacharya solution instead

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! Do you know if Office 2021 is good for this or only Office 365 does?

Comment: Will work only on Excel 365, but I see you got working solution provided already

Answer (score 0):

This will filter errors/blanks in rows 15, 20, 21, and 22.

```
=SUM(TOCOL(MAP(C3:C10,LAMBDA(m,SUM(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(m,CHAR(10)))))),2))
```

[image]